# Vertical seperator in aspx page in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, separator

I want to display buttons arranged in vertical arrangements and vertical separator and right side have gridview.

I tried below code. But nothing changes happened.

```
 <body bgcolor="#CCFFFF">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">  
    <!--Right side of webpage -->
       <div>
         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
               Text="ImportData to Database" Width="187px"            
               style="top: 40px; left: 228px; position: absolute; height: 29px; right: 824px;" />      

        <asp:DropDownList ID="MonthList" runat="server" 
            onselectedindexchanged="MonthList_SelectedIndexChanged"  
            style="top: 141px; left: 380px; position: absolute; height: -5px; width: 95px; ">
        </asp:DropDownList> 

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
            onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            style="top: 244px; left: 256px; position: absolute; height: 152px; width: 287px"> 
             <columns>         
                    <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Select">
                        <itemtemplate>
                            <asp:checkbox ID="cbSelect"  runat="server"></asp:checkbox>
                        </itemtemplate>
                    </asp:templatefield>                
                </columns>
        </asp:GridView>
     </div>
    <!--Left side -->
        <div style="float:left; width:30%;">
        <asp:Button ID="Userbtn" runat="server" Text="User Settings"       
            style="top: 87px; left: 14px; position: absolute; height: 29px; width: 145px" />
        <asp:Button ID="EmployeeBtn" runat="server" 
            style="top: 40px; left: 14px; position: absolute; height: 29px; width: 143px" 
            Text="Add Employee " />
         </div>

     </form>
```

Comment: I am not a web designer but there was a vertical separator in one of my project. I guess it was an image that was adjusted as a back-ground to left div

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work

```html
<body bgcolor="#CCFFFF">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
   
             <!--Left side -->
        <div style="float:left; width:30%;">
        <asp:Button ID="Userbtn" runat="server" Text="User Settings"       
            style="top: 87px; left: 14px; position: absolute; height: 29px; width: 145px" />
        <asp:Button ID="EmployeeBtn" runat="server" 
            style="top: 40px; left: 14px; position: absolute; height: 29px; width: 143px" 
            Text="Add Employee " />
         </div>
      
        <!-- Right Side -->
   
         <div style="float:right; border-left:5px solid #000000;" width:70%;" >
   
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
               Text="ImportData to Database" Width="187px"            
               style="top: 40px; left: 228px; position:static; height: 29px; margin-left:10px; " />      
    <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="MonthList" runat="server" 
            onselectedindexchanged="MonthList_SelectedIndexChanged"  
            style="top: 141px; left: 380px; position: inherit; height: -5px; width: 95px; ">
        </asp:DropDownList> <br />

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
            onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            style="top: 244px; left: 256px; position: static; height: 152px; width:287px; margin-left:10px; margin-bottom:25px;"> 
             <columns>         
                    <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Select">
                        <itemtemplate>
                            <asp:checkbox ID="cbSelect"  runat="server"></asp:checkbox>
                        </itemtemplate>
                    </asp:templatefield>                
                </columns>
        </asp:GridView>

        </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Always a good idea to explain exactly what you've done, rather than expect readers to inspect your answer line by line to try and figure out what has changed.  By all means, have the example, but give people a clue what your suggesting

Answer (score 0):

Check with this code:

```
<body bgcolor="#CCFFFF">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">  
        <!--Right side of webpage -->
           <div style="float:left; width:70%;">
             <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
                   Text="ImportData to Database" Width="187px"            
                   style="top: 40px; left: 228px; position: absolute; height: 29px; right: 824px;" />      

            <asp:DropDownList ID="MonthList" runat="server" 
                onselectedindexchanged="MonthList_SelectedIndexChanged"  
                style="top: 141px; left: 380px; position: absolute; height: -5px; width: 95px; ">
            </asp:DropDownList> 

            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
                onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                style="top: 244px; left: 256px; position: absolute; height: 152px; width: 287px"> 
                 <columns>         
                        <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Select">
                            <itemtemplate>
                                <asp:checkbox ID="cbSelect"  runat="server"></asp:checkbox>
                            </itemtemplate>
                        </asp:templatefield>                
                    </columns>
            </asp:GridView>
         </div>

        <!--Left side -->
          <div style="float:left; width:30%;">
            <asp:Button ID="Userbtn" runat="server" Text="User Settings" style="top: 87px; left: 14px; position: absolute; height: 29px; width: 145px" />
            <asp:Button ID="EmployeeBtn" runat="server" 
                style="top: 40px; left: 14px; position: absolute; height: 29px; width: 143px" 
                Text="Add Employee " />
          </div>

 </form>
```